# Gluon Mobile Share Button Implementation

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Does Gluon Mobile have any guidance on implementing a share button? My goal is to be able to share a string containing a link to different apps on the phone. **At the moment, I need this only for the iOS implementation.** I was able to find this [link](http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/) that provides a simple way to do this in Objective-C:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codingexplorer.com/"];

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Looking at the [GoNative](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/) application example on the Gluon website, it seems like I can use the above code snippet where needed as the native iOS code. Do I have to update the ios build gradle to account for the UIActivity class mentioned in the first link above?

**Update***

I have been able to get this to work based on help in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969849/go-native-app-not-working-correctly-gluon-mobile).

However when trying to install the native library, I get this error which is understandable as `self` is unknown in the scope of the code. How would I be able to do this? Instantiate a popover or dialog and pass the `activityVC` to it?

`/Users/ashishsharma/NetBeansProjects/konfamdbranch/src/ios/n‌​ative/Share.m:25:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'self' [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this using examples on the internet (shown above) along with going through the existing code for the Barcode Scan Service. The issue I was experiencing with the above code was that the present view controller could not be found. However, looking at the bit bucket source for [Barcode Scan](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/dd598e67be7827ab3861d9f0831d4e5d6da47f3f/plugins/plugin-barcode-scan/ios/src/main/native/BarcodeScan.m?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), I was able to get the root view with the following code:

```
if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow])
{
    NSLog(@"key window was nil");
    return;
}

// get the root view controller
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
if(!rootViewController)
{
    NSLog(@"rootViewController was nil");
    return;
}
```

Then in the code snippet I placed in the question, replace `self` with `rootViewController`:

```
[rootViewController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This leads to the modified code snippet:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#include "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/jni.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL     Java_com_gluonhq_charm_down_plugins_ios_IOSShareService_shareMessage
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass, jstring jMessage) {

    if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow])
    {
        NSLog(@"key window was nil");
        return;
    }

    // get the root view controller
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
    if(!rootViewController)
    {
        NSLog(@"rootViewController was nil");
        return;
    }

    NSString *textToShare = @"Check out this site!";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

   [rootViewController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**Note I followed the GoNative application to generate my objective-c/ios files correctly.**

This leads to a minimal functionality share implementation **only because I don't have Facebook installed on the IPhone simulator.**

[image]